# Can I make part of my preferences a dynamic list?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to make a screen that will add options as the user clicks on another preference.

Comment: saved prefs or application prefs?

Comment: application. What I have been trying to do is start an activity with a listview after clicking on a preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set dependencies in your Preferences.  That way you can enable or disable blocks based on other options.  Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android%3adependency) for details.